# How to clear a list in C

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to create a function to "clean" a list: to free the elements and s_struct (->next) (done by the ft_lstdelone function). I've got an issue: the code at the top doesn't work whereas the second one works; any ideas?

#### Non-working code

```
void    ft_lstclear(t_list **lst, void (*del)(void*))
{
    t_list  *temp;
    t_list  *begin;

    if (!lst || !*lst || !del)
        return ;
    begin = *lst;
    while (begin)
    {
        temp = (begin)->next;
        ft_lstdelone((begin), del);
        (begin) = temp;
    }
 }
```

#### Working code

```
void    ft_lstclear(t_list **lst, void (*del)(void*))
{
    t_list  *begin;

    if (!lst || !*lst)
        return ;
    while (*lst != NULL)
    {
        begin = (*lst)->next;
        ft_lstdelone((*lst), del);
        (*lst) = begin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please enter your code as a code block so that it's easily searchable and can be copy-pasted. Never use images to show code.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an adequate description of the problem. /// They are identical except in two regards: 1) The first doesn't change `*lst` while the second one assigns `NULL` to it. 2) The first does nothing if `del` is `NULL` while the second doesn't check `del`.

Comment: The first code never assigns to `*lst`, so that the list head is not set null.  Whether that's a good idea is a separate discussion.  Note that your code is supposed to call the function pointer `del`, not `ft_lstdelone()`.  As it is, you aren't really using the `del` variable in the code, though the compiler won't complain because you pass it to the recursive call.  The parentheses in `(begin) = temp;` and `(*lst) = begin;` are superfluous but mostly harmless; similarly with `temp = (begin)->next;`.  However, in `begin = (*lst)->next;` the parentheses are anything but superfluous.

Comment: @ikegami i disagree with what you said : by saying begin = *lst, begin is a pointer and is pointing on (*lst), so begin->next is like (*lst)->next. With the first code, i m working on (*lst)

Comment: Re "*`begin` is a pointer and is pointing on `*lst`*", No, `begin` is a copy of `*lst`, which means `begin` originally points to `**lst`. But that's is relevant. I said you only change `*lst` (the variable to which `lst` points) in one of the snippets.   `begin = *lst; begin = NULL;` is not the same thing as `*lst = NULL;`. The former changes `begin` (twice), while the second changes `*lst`.

Answer (score 1):

By "not work", I imagine you are referring to the fact that the variable in the caller isn't updated.

The second snippet basically ends with this:

```c
...
*lst = NULL;   // When `temp` eventually becomes `NULL`.
```

The equivalent would be

```c
begin = *lst;
...
begin = NULL;   // When `temp` eventually becomes `NULL`.
*lst = begin;
```

You're missing that last line. Your snippet never updates `*lst`, the variable in the caller.

Fixed:

```c
void ft_lstclear( t_list **lst, void ( *del )( void* ) )
{
    t_list *begin = *lst;
    while ( begin )
    {
        t_list *temp = begin->next;
        ft_lstdelone( begin, del );
        begin = temp;
    }

    *lst = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the first example, just do:

```
*lst = begin;
```

at the end of the function.

---

You didn't post the struct definition or the `del` function, so I had to synthesize them.

Here is the refactored code [partial]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    struct list *next;
    char *data;
} t_list;

// ft_lstfree -- release any storage
void
ft_lstfree(void *nodep)
{
    t_list *node = nodep;
    free(node->data);
    free(node);
}

void
ft_lstdelone(t_list *lst,void (*del)(void *))
{

    del(lst);
}

void
ft_lstclear1(t_list **lst, void (*del)(void *))
{
    t_list *temp;
    t_list *begin;

    if (!lst || !*lst || !del)
        return;

    begin = *lst;
    while (begin) {
        temp = (begin)->next;
        ft_lstdelone((begin), del);
        (begin) = temp;
    }

// NOTE/FIX: we must pass this back to caller
#if 1
    *lst = begin;
#endif
}

void
ft_lstclear2(t_list **lst, void (*del)(void *))
{
    t_list *begin;

#if 0
    if (!lst || !*lst)
        return;
#else
    if (!lst || !*lst || !del)
        return;
#endif

    while (*lst != NULL) {
        begin = (*lst)->next;
        ft_lstdelone((*lst), del);
        (*lst) = begin;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    t_list *list = NULL;

    ft_lstclear1(&list,ft_lstfree);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

But, what you're calling `t_list` is actually a *node* [of a linked list].

You're doing a list by passing a double pointer.

I prefer a separate list struct and a separate node struct:

1. You *always* pass a pointer to a list. And, not a double pointer to functions that change the list and a single pointer to functions that don't change the list (e.g. `ft_lstprint`).
2. You can easily add `tail` pointer
3. Early prep for converting from a singly linked list to a doubly linked list.

Here is how I'd do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char *data;
} t_node;

typedef struct {
    t_node *head;
    t_node *tail;
} t_list;

// ft_nodefree -- release any storage
void
ft_nodefree(void *nodep)
{
    t_node *node = nodep;
    free(node->data);
    free(node);
}

void
ft_nodedelone(t_node *node,void (*del)(void *))
{

    del(node);
}

void
ft_lstclear1(t_list *lst, void (*del)(void *))
{
    t_node *temp;
    t_node *begin;

    // no list
    if (lst == NULL)
        return;

    // no delete function
    if (del == NULL)
        return;

    for (begin = lst->head;  begin != NULL;  begin = temp) {
        temp = begin->next;
        ft_nodedelone(begin,del);
    }

    lst->head = begin;
    lst->tail = begin;
}

int
main(void)
{
    t_list list = { NULL };

    ft_lstclear1(&list,ft_nodefree);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> By doing lst = begin, i m just saying at the end of my function "ok let s now ponting and so point at the end of my list", because begin has already move from begin = *lst to begin->next...->next **************************************** void ft_lstdelone(t_list *lst, void (*del)(void)) { if (!lst) return ; if ((*del)) (*del)(lst->content); free(lst); } –
> VictordeLeusse

I'm not sure I understand you. In the code, you end up with an *empty* list. There is *no* end anymore. The caller's list pointer will end up with `NULL`.

Calling the function `ft_lstclear` is a bit of a misnomer. Based on what it does, it might be better called `ft_lstdestroy`.

This may be an arbitrary distinction for your code, but, with a separate list struct (as in my final example), we'd need a separate function:

```
void
ft_lstdestroy(t_list *lst, void (*del)(void *))
{

    ft_lstclear1(lst,del);
    free(lst);
}
```

Comment: By doing *lst = begin, i m just saying at the end of my function "ok let s now ponting and so point at the end of my list", because begin has already move from begin = *lst to begin->next...->next                                                                                                                                         ****************************************                                                                                            
 void ft_lstdelone(t_list *lst, void (*del)(void*))
{
 if (!lst)
  return ;
 if ((*del))
  (*del)(lst->content);
 free(lst);
}

Comment: `*lst = begin;` is an obfuscated way of writing `*lst = NULL;`

Comment: @ikegami Doing `*lst = begin;` is more general. It's what you'd want to do when you have: `begin = *lst; do_stuff_with_begin ...; *lst = begin;`. You're dereferencing `*lst` initially so you can use single level pointers in most of the code and not have to do `(*lst)` everywhere. Then, you put back the _updated_ value. The last line doesn't have to know whether `begin` will be null or not. Thus, it works in functions like `ft_del_first_two_elements`. Using `NULL` at the end is a special case.